# C - Comparing string literal with character array

Tags: c, arrays, string, character, strcmp

I am new to C and am still a bit confused about how to use strings via character arrays.

In my C program, I am accepting commands from the user:

```
char command[20];
scanf("%s",command);
```

Of course, afterwards I want to figure out what command they typed (something similar to: "`if (command == "hello")`, then do something"). I know this is not possible in C because I am comparing a string literal to a character array, but what would be a good way to it? I have tried using `strcmp(command, "hello")` and still got errors.

Any advice you can provide would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What "errors", precisely? `strcmp()` is the way to go.

Comment: Also, the single worst error I see in your code is the use of `scanf()`. Forget that function altogether. You are looking for `fgets(command, sizeof command, stdin)` instead.

Comment: (The main reason behind not using scanf; there's no limit to how much it could scan. What if the user inputs 21 characters?)

Comment: Furthermore, a string literal **is** a character array itself, by the way.

Comment: @DennisMeng And it doesn't scan whitespace using `%s` by default, it pretends to understand regexes but it doesn't, etc, etc...

Comment: That too. But letting the user overflow your buffer is scarier than screwing up regexes.

Comment: @H2CO3: It doesn't pretend to understand regexes, it just implements a scanning syntax that's less powerful than regexes. Buffer overflow can be avoided by using, for example, `scanf("%20s", command);`. But `fgets()` followed by `sscanf()` is more robust.

Comment: @KeithThompson What I was referring to is merely that the syntax of `scanf()` format strings can very easily be misleading to someone who just started out with programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

strcmp returns 0 when the strings are the same. I have code that uses strcmp comparing character arrays to string literals, and I was quite confused when it wasn't working. Turns out it was wrong for me to assume it would return 1 when the string are the same!

Maybe you've made the same mistake?

Comment: Indeed, making assumptions is the incorrect way of writing programs - one should read the documentation instead.

Answer (score 15):

I have written a complete version of what I think you are trying to do:

```
    #include <string.h>
    void main()
    {

       char command[20];
       scanf("%s",command);

       // command and "hello" can be less than, equal or greater than!
       // thus, strcmp return 3 possible values
       if (strcmp(command, "hello") == 0)
       {
          printf("\nThe user said hello!");
       }

    }
```

Several people have commented about using `scanf` and they are correct, except that a new programmer has to start somewhere in learning this stuff, so don't feel too bad we are all learning...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you were all right. The problem was that I thought strcmp was simply a boolean function, when in reality it returns 3 possible values. And I will try to use fgets once I become more familiar with it. The reason why I am using scanf is that I need to read the command typed by the user up until the first white space (not the whole line, since I need to read two commands per line). Once I figure out how to control what I am reading with fgets, I will definitely use it. Thanks for the advice with fgets, and thanks so much everybody for the thorough answers! You are so helpful!

Comment: You mind upvoting useful answers and selecting one as the right answer?

Comment: RSinghS - I have tried but I need to have 15 reputation to upvote answers. I will definitely upvote the useful answers once I am able to! :)

Comment: @Irina, I think if it is your question you can select the "correct" answer, from your point of view!! This is different than upvoting but it does provide useful feedback.

Comment: Understood and done. Thanks and sorry! Still new around here. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a perfect starting point for you:

http://www.wikihow.com/Compare-Two-Strings-in-C-Programming

It's probably written at the right level for you.  Good luck and welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

When talking about string in C, it normally takes two forms: 1. a character array, 2. a character pointer. Most of the time, they are interchangeable. For example:

```
char *cmd_ptr = "command1";
char cmd_array[20] = "command2";
printf ("cmd1: %s cmd2: %s\n", cmd_ptr, cmd_array);
```

The main difference for the above definition is that for `cmd_ptr` you could not change its content like `cmd_ptr[0] = 'a';` for `cmd_array` you could change any element in the array.

But you could do `cmd_ptr = cmd_array;` then you could make changes through `cmd_ptr` as it points to the same location as `cmd_array`.